# Using Oracle, from microseconds to 6 seconds interval

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

I have high frequency tick data which need to sort from microsecond to 6 seconds interval. The daily tick data start from 09:15:00.000 EST, and end at 15:15:00.000 EST.

This is my `temp2` table:

```
 date1                       | close1 | volume1
-----------------------------+--------+---------
 2010-04-16 09:15:28.010 EST |  10001 |       4
 2010-04-16 09:16:00.020 EST |  10002 |       5
 2010-04-16 09:16:35.030 EST |  10003 |       6
 2010-04-16 09:16:35.040 EST |  10001 |       3
 2010-04-16 15:14:59.050 EST |  10007 |       3
 2010-04-19 09:15:05.050 EST |  10002 |       1
 ...                         |    ... |     ...
```

(`date1` is a `VARCHAR2(28)`; `close1` and `volume1` are both `NUMBER`s).

How do I get the following result?

```
 date2               | close2 | volume2
---------------------+--------+---------
 2010-04-16 09:15:30 |  10001 |       4
 2010-04-16 09:16:06 |  10002 |       5
 2010-04-16 09:16:36 |  10001 |       9
 2010-04-16 15:15:00 |  10007 |       3
 2010-04-19 09:15:06 |  10002 |       1
 ...                 |    ... |     ...
```

The `close2` column use last_value of interval 00, 06, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54. and if microseconds in range 00-05.999, just set `close2` column value as last_vlue of the interval, set `volume2` column value as sum of `volume1` of the interval.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between your input data and your output; could you elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: If you're storing timestamps then store them in a `timestamp` datatype, sorting is easy after that...

Comment: @ruakh: the close2 column use last_value of interval 00, 06, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54. and if microseconds in range 00-05.999, just set close2 column value as last_vlue of the interval, set volume2 column value as sum of  volume1 of the interval.

Comment: You can convert the varchar2 field into a timestamp datatype with to_timestamp

Comment: Work pressure is so high, so is urgent to need expert help me. Keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than packing all the logic into a single query — which is possible, but incredibly ugly and painful — I think it makes sense to create a stored-procedure that translates your `date1` to your `date2`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date1_to_date2 (date1 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN varchar2
IS

  ts TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

  ts := TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(date1, 1, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

  IF SUBSTR(date1, 21, 3) > 0 THEN
    ts := ts + NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'SECOND');
  END IF;

  ts := ts + NUMTODSINTERVAL(MOD(60 - TO_CHAR(ts, 'SS'), 6), 'SECOND');

  RETURN TO_CHAR(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

END date1_to_date2;
/

SHOW ERRORS;
```

Then the rest, while not exactly straightforward, is nonetheless palatable:

```
SELECT date2,
       close1 AS close2,
       volume2
  FROM ( SELECT date2,
                close1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date2 ORDER BY date1 DESC) AS rn,
                SUM(volume1) OVER (PARTITION BY date2) AS volume2
           FROM ( SELECT date1,
                         date1_to_date2(date1) AS date2,
                         close1,
                         volume1
                    FROM temp2
                )
       )
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY date2
;
```

(You can actually do it with just one subquery, by substituting the definition of `date2` everywhere — and maybe even without any subquery at all, if the `WHERE rn = 1` can be converted into a `HAVING` clause, which I didn't try — but I think this is the clearest way.)

Comment: Thanks your help, Rurkh, the new arrangement of the content in the ask  which modified by your is neat and beautiful. and your brilliant works  supply me a deep and new aspect of Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

The core of the problem is to convert the timestamps you have into 'buckets' corresponding to your 6-second intervals. One way to do this is by extracting the portion of the date up to the minute, which can be done with the [`TRUNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#sthref1718) function, and the number of seconds as a separate value. (Note that I'm treating `date1` as if it's already a `TIMESTAMP`, as recommended in the comments and an answer to a previous question of yours, but if it stays as a `VARCHAR` then you'll need to convert it):

```
select trunc(date1, 'MI'), extract(second from date1) from temp2;

2010-04-16 09:15:00   28.01
2010-04-16 09:16:00     .02
2010-04-16 09:16:00   35.03
2010-04-16 09:16:00   35.04
2010-04-16 15:14:00   59.05
2010-04-19 09:15:00    5.05
```

... and then manipulating the seconds portion to get it to round up to your window:

```
select trunc(date1, 'MI'),
    6 * (trunc(1 + extract(second from date1) / 6))
from temp2;

2010-04-16 09:15:00   30.00
2010-04-16 09:16:00    6.00
2010-04-16 09:16:00   36.00
2010-04-16 09:16:00   36.00
2010-04-16 15:14:00   60.00
2010-04-19 09:15:00    6.00
```

... and finally add them together, doing date arithmetic by diving the 'seconds' window by 86400, the number of seconds in a day:

```
select trunc(date1,'MI')
    + (6 * trunc(1 + (extract(second from date1) / 6)))/(24*60*60)
from temp2;
```

... and as you're multiplying then dividing, this can be reduced slightly to:

```
select trunc(date1,'MI')
    + trunc(1 + (extract(second from date1) / 6))/(24*60*10)
from temp2;

2010-04-16 09:15:30
2010-04-16 09:16:06
2010-04-16 09:16:36
2010-04-16 09:16:36
2010-04-16 15:15:00
2010-04-19 09:15:06
```

Now you can use this as the basis for some [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407) to get the required value for the other fields, something like:

```
select distinct date2,
    first_value(close1) over (partition by date2 order by date1 desc) as close2,
    sum(volume1) over (partition by date2) as volume2
from (
    select date1, close1, volume1, trunc(date1,'MI')
        + trunc(1 + (extract(second from date1) / 6))/(24*60*10) as date2
    from temp2
)
order by date2, close2, volume2;

DATE2                   CLOSE2    VOLUME2
------------------- ---------- ----------
2010-04-16 09:15:30      10001          4
2010-04-16 09:16:06      10002          5
2010-04-16 09:16:36      10001          9
2010-04-16 15:15:00      10007          3
2010-04-19 09:15:06      10002          1
```

I'm tacking the interval version of the date onto the existing columns and making the whole thing an inline view, since we need all the original columns too; and for each `date2` I'm getting the latest `close1` value using the [`FIRST_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions066.htm#sthref1134) function (with `desc` in the ordering), and the analytic version of [`SUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions182.htm#sthref1590) to get the total of `volume1` for that window. The `distinct` is there because the anayltics provide the same values for both 09:16:36 rows, but you only want one of them in this case.

Comment: you are so talent and smart, Thnaks your hearted help. A very good solution.

Comment: Alex Poole, My two questions is solved by your and also the other expert, how happy I am now. Thanks you spend so much time to study my questions. Greetings from me.

Comment: Interesting.  First time I've even heard of `extract` function.